# What would be an equivalent meaning expression?

Tags: meaning, expressions

There is a saying in portuguese:

> Pare de guardar gelo no bolso!

Something like "Stop keeping ice in your pocket", meaning that you should stop doing something that is useless.

Is there an expression with this meaning in English language?

Comment: There's Ice in winter, and Bringing coals to Newcastle, both worthless activities.

Comment: *That's about as useful as a chocolate tea-pot*

*We need that like a fish needs a bicycle*